# Replicating Snapchat keyboard behavior

Tags: ios, swift

Snapchat's keyboard behavior works differently than any other keyboard I have seen. When a user drags on the input bar, it scrolls up or down with the drag.

How do they do this? It's unclear how they are able to even access the keyboard frame.

Link to video of the behavior:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ssxx.jpg

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/keyboarddismissmode/ondrag). You'll need to be using a scroll view/tableview/collection view I think

Comment: @aheze the issue is not when scrolling the collection view. Rather, it's when scrolling the input bar is when I'm having trouble recreating the effect.